# read/replace jboss system properties in a jsp file

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I have set system properties in JBoss 6.  I have deployed a war file and everything works fine.  The next step I'd like to take is to read those system properties replacing variables in the default index.jsp file to show in the users browser. First, I'll admit I may not be going at this correctly but I need certain properties to display based on what instance the user is connecting to.  Maybe there's a better way than what I'm thinking.  Any help would be totally appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the idea that the javascript would be client side so I was having difficulty understanding how it would be done.  Here's a snippet of my jsp file and how I was able to get it to work.

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">

<%@ page import="javax.naming.Context" %>
<%@ page import="javax.naming.InitialContext" %>
<% 
...

String dbUrl = System.getProperty("jboss.db.connectionString"); 

...
%>
...
```